# Get the text of the recent javascript alert

Tags: c#, javascript, text, alert, mshtml

I'm writing an IE extension using mshtml. Is there a way to get the text from the recent alert displayed to the user (via C# or javascript)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't u just save the thing u alerted before?

Comment: actually I'm writing a monitor for web sites, and my application simply tracks the user's steps. So I don't know how to find out whether an alert had occurred in the result of any action.

Comment: can u inject js into that website?

Answer (score 0):

If you can hijack/inject/exec any JS in your websites, you could just overwrite the alert method with a custom one, which calls the original one inside :) Something like this:

```
// let's save the alert first
var _super_original_alert = window.alert;
// and now we overwrite it
window.alert = function(s){
  // do something with the received string
  // i will just log it, but you might want to send the string via
  // ajax/jsonp to a remote server
  console.log(s)

  // call the original intended alert
  _super_original_alert(s)
}
```

It's not nice, but could do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think that's just what I need

Comment: will this work even if page has jquery? Also, can we apply same logic for confirm? Can anyone update this for confirm? or validate my code `var oldconfirm = window.confirm; window.confirm = function(msg){ document.___LastConfirm = msg; console.log(msg); return oldconfirm(msg); } ` Here I am trying to store the msg as document property, so that I can access it later.

Comment: var oldConfirm = window.confirm; window.confirm = function(s) { window.lastConfirmationMessage = s; return oldConfirm(s) }; confirm('omnom'); window.lastConfirmationMessage => 'omnom'

Comment: One more issue. I was able to work method of alert provided by you but on some pages it gives error like too much recursion. I am not able to understand it. Though it works. But now the real problem. This alert comes after the submit action on the page, when I click on submit, it validates something & then shows the alert message like say so and so object is created successfully.When I see the console the log statement is not shown.Also, once OK button is clicked, the browser window itself gets closed so I am not able to get the text.Do u know any better way to get text from alert in Firefox?